# Using #define with functions

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I've been reading through the Python source code for kicks the last couple days, and I came across something I didn't understand. In the "abstract.c" file I found the below code snippet. I thought I understood how it worked, but then I realized I had no clue where the `*v` and `*w` come from. Could somebody please explain what is going on in this code, and an example of how you would use it?

```
#define BINARY_FUNC(func, op, op_name) \
    PyObject * \
    func(PyObject *v, PyObject *w) { \
        return binary_op(v, w, NB_SLOT(op), op_name); \
}

BINARY_FUNC(PyNumber_Or, nb_or, "|")
BINARY_FUNC(PyNumber_Xor, nb_xor, "^")
BINARY_FUNC(PyNumber_And, nb_and, "&")
BINARY_FUNC(PyNumber_Lshift, nb_lshift, "<<")
BINARY_FUNC(PyNumber_Rshift, nb_rshift, ">>")
BINARY_FUNC(PyNumber_Subtract, nb_subtract, "-")
BINARY_FUNC(PyNumber_Divmod, nb_divmod, "divmod()")
```

Comment: They don't come from anywhere, they're just literal parts of the macro expansion. They're the names given to the parameters of the functions being defined.

Comment: @Barmar, You should make that an answer.

Comment: It's no different than normally defining a function: `int f(int x, int y){return x*y;)}`. `x` and `y` are only defined for this function. To fully explain what's going on, you'd have to let us know how `binary_op` and `NB_SLOT` are defined.

Comment: Run it through the pre-processor and inspect its output, this might help to enlighten.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`v` and `w` are not macro parameters, they're literal parts of the expansion. The macro expands into a function definition, and the function takes parameters -- they're always named `v` and `w`, and they're of type `PythonObject *`. For example:

```
BINARY_FUNC(PyNumber_Or, nb_or, "|")
```

expands into:

```
PythonObject *
PyNumber_Or(PyObject *v, PyObject *w) {
    return binary_op(v, w, NB_SLOT(nb_or), "|");
}
```

Comment: Ahh, gotcha. I don't know why I didn't see that before. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
#define BINARY_FUNC(func, op, op_name) \
PyObject * \
func(PyObject *v, PyObject *w) { \
    return binary_op(v, w, NB_SLOT(op), op_name); \
}

BINARY_FUNC(PyNumber_Or, nb_or, "|")
```

The `BINARY_FUNC` defination I included above expands to:

```
PyObject *PyNumber_Or(PyObject *v, PyObject *w) { 
    return binary_op(v, w, NB_SLOT(nb_or), "|");
}
```

An entire function where the `u` and `v` pointers are part of the function.  Of course, there is no parenthesis safety so it would be pretty darn easy to break when passing in "bad" values...